# Folium: Is it possible to select and export markers within an area by drawing

Tags: python, folium

I am using the Folium library for Python and would like to export the coordinates of specific markers that are within a drawing (Polygon, Circle, Rectangle)

Below is the code:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import Draw, MarkerCluster
from folium import plugins

m = folium.Map([25.143591,55.193512], zoom_start=10)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster(control=False).add_to(m)

for _,row in data_df.iterrows():
    location = row[['latitude','longitude']].tolist()
    folium.Marker(row[['latitude','longitude']]).add_to(marker_cluster)
    
    


draw = Draw(
            export=True,
            filename='data.geojson',
            position='topleft',
            draw_options={'polyline': False,
                          'circlemarker': False,
                          'polygon': False,
                          'marker': False},
            edit_options={'poly': {'allowIntersection': False}})

draw.add_to(m)

m
```

What I would like to achieve is the ability to export on,ly the 2 markers that are within this box:

[image]

Would this be possible to do with folium? Or maybe there is another Python library that has this functionality?